# C# Static Class cannot be found

Tags: c#, class, oop, static, xna

I created a static class to keep all my "level" arrays in (I'm writing a game in monogame, using XNA).

The problem is that i can't use the class anywhere, it just won't show up in intellisense, and returns an error `The name 'Rooms' does not exist in the current context`. Any idea what may cause this?

```
namespace Marked_V0._2
{
    public static class Rooms
    {
        static public int[,] Level1 = new int[,]
        {
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
        };
    }
}
```

Error:

```
CS1002 ; Expected
CS1001 Identifier expected
CS0103 The name 'Rooms' does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: Check your namespace.

Comment: Wherever you want to use this class, in that class write this at the top of the class above the namespace: `using Marked_V0._2;`

Comment: Also, on a side note it returns an `int[,]` not an `int` so watch what you assign it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace for `Rooms` most likely does not match the namespace of the rest of the project. You can either change the namespace or include the extra namespace with `using Marked_V0._2`.